# php __construct what is wrong with this

Tags: php, pdo, constructor

What's wrong with my code:

```
class Database
{
private $db;
public function __construct() 
{
$dbname = 'dbname';
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'dbpass';

$connStr = "mysql:$dbhost; dbname=$dbname";
try
{
    $this->db = new PDO($connStr, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} 
catch (Exception $ex) 
{
    echo $ex->getMessage();
    exit;
}   
}

public function getTableFromSQLQuery($query, $params)
{
$db = $this->db;
$result = $this->db->prepare($query);
if (isset($params) && count($params)>0)
    foreach($params as $key=>$param)
    $result->bindParam ($key, $param);
$result->execute();
return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

}

and call this from code:

```
$db = new Database();
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";   
$rowsCategories = $db->getTableFromSQLQuery($query, null);
```

the error: **Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected'** 

The problem in debugger it loses $db in class Database, why? If I each time use $db = new PDO(all params) it works, but if I use with constructor - it doesn't. Help, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Connection string should be

```
$connStr = "mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname";
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already found this problem. It's strange, because I copied this code from previous working project.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$connStr` to:

```
$connStr = "mysql:host=". $dbhost .";dbname=". $dbname;
```

Comment: This is still incorrect. You're missing `host=` and why add additional overhead with concatenation? It's not needed within double quoted strings...